# Getting error while running any GRAILS COMMAND in the console{CMD}

Tags: grails

```
grails> grails compile
| Running pre-compiled script
| Error Script not found for name
```

NOTE:: This is the error i am facing for any GRAILS command{for Example: grails compile, grails clean etc} running in the console.

Answer (score 3):

You already in grails context.
Type only compile command.